# Set Object to instance of itself VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, reflection

I'm working with a test object right now as a proof of concept for a very large object(700 or so properties).

Basically what I'm trying to do is set the data in the object with a new constructor without having to manually set the properties because there are so many. for example

```
Person.Name = "Bob"
Person.Age = 30
etc...
```

Instead, what I'm trying to do is iterate through the properties in the object via reflection and set the properties in the object.  Data is coming in from a mainframe in a gigantic string...

```
Private _person As Person

Public Sub New(ByVal personData As String)
    _person = TryCast(ConvertStringToObject(personData, Me.GetType), Person)
End Sub

Public Property FirstName As String
    Get
        Return _person.FirstName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _person.FirstName = value
    End Set
End Property

 Private Function ConvertStringToObject(ByVal data As String, ByVal obj As Object) As Object

    Dim objectType As Type = obj.GetType
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = objectType.GetProperties

    For Each objProperty As PropertyInfo In properties

        'just an example... not really how i get data...
        Dim value As String = data.Substring(0, 10)

        objProperty.SetValue(obj, value, Nothing)

    Next

    Return obj

End Function
```

So when I run this code I get an object reference set error as soon as the property first name is set (first property)... It's seems like I have created a paradox of sorts... I'm trying to set something before it exists but to make it exist I need to fill it first.

The method I am using needs to be generic because it's working with a bunch of different objects which is why I'm returning an object.

I've done similar things in the past but with and entity from entity framework built into a model of an MVC form but in that case I had two different object so there was no issue.

As it stands right now my convertStringToObject method is off on it's own and I just call it and cast it to the object I want but I would really like to have it in a base class and have the other object inherit it and use a new constructor. So code looks like:

```
dim person as new Person 
person = TryCast(ConvertStringToObject(dataString,person), Person)
```

Again not really a lot of code but would still like to have the conversion go on inside the class via the new constructor...

Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i such scenarios when construction of an object is a complex or time taking task, we apply either of factory pattern or builder pattern. For the task you want to accomplish Builder pattern is the perfect match. The peson class is carrying a large amount of data (for those 700 properties). hence we also need to decouple the data-transfer from business-model-validations. Here is how to do it:

### First Decouple the data-model and the validations

```
Class PersonData
    Public Name as String
    Public Age as integer
    ...
    ...and 700 more...
End Class

Class person
   private _personData as PersonData = nothing

   sub new(personData as PersonData)
       _personData = personData
   end sub

   property Name as string
       get
           return _personData.Name
       end get
       set(value as string)
           ...the validations here...
           _personData.Name = value
       end set
    end property
End Class
```

### Then define the instantiation process

```
MustInherit Class PersonBuilder
    protected _stringRepresentation as String

    sub setString(stringRep as string)
        _stringRepresentation = stringRep
    end sub

    function BuildPerson as Person
end class
```

**One way to build concrete instances would be by using *loooong* string from mainframe**

```
class MainFramePersonBuilder
    inherits PesonBuilder

    overrides function BuildPerson as Person
         dim pData as PersonData
         pData = DeserializeMainFrameString(_stringRepresentation)
         return new Person(pData)
    end sub

    private function DeserializeMainframeString(mString as string) as personData
         ... do the reflection stuff here...
         ... dont use person class direcctly...
         ... rather use the PersonData structure...

         return thePersonData
    end sub
```

**another way would be to to do so using data fetched from some web service**
i know it is not in scope but this architecture will help if that requirement comes.

```
 class JSONPersonBuilder
    inherits PersonBuilder

    overrides function BuildPerson as person
        return new Person(DeserializeJSONString(_stringRepresentation))
    end function

  end class
```

### so in your code you can write

```
 dim pb as PersonBuilder = new MainFramePersonBuilder() 'JSONPersonBuilder
 pb.setString(mainFrameString) ' JSONString
 dim p as Person = pb.BuildPerson()
```

now if you in you need to transfer the `Person` to some different place over network or over your own webservice, you dont need to send the mainFrameString. serialize the PersonData and send it. you will be isolating your clients from your servers - your PersonData being the middle tier.

Comment: Ok, so in this instance I'm duplicating the person class with the PersonData class filling one and setting it to another?  I tried out the code and it works but I'm a little concerned about the overhead.  This is an interesting approach though!

Comment: Edited my post to contain how my ConvertStringToObject method is currently being used.

Comment: of course there is overhead but then entropy does increase as we go up in abstraction. this is a classic tradeoff bet. performance and maintainability. the part of code we are talking about forms the business layer and changes frequently. hence things need to be highly decoupled. this single code will soon be exposed simultaneously over web-service, sdk-library, web-interface, desktop-interface and so on.  what happens *after* is that a guy comes up and asks you to integrate the `person` with his facebook profile. to hell with the mainframe. BTW do google up `memento-pattern` and `dto-pattern`

Comment: I'll have a look into those other patterns you mentioned.  Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of needing a private variable for holding your current object instance, you already have a variable available, `Me`. Below is the adjusted code which uses `Me` as the target for setting its property values:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal personData As String)
    ConvertStringToObject(personData)
End Sub

Public Property FirstName As String

 Private Sub ConvertStringToObject(ByVal data As String)

    Dim objectType As Type = Me.GetType
    Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = objectType.GetProperties

    For Each objProperty As PropertyInfo In properties

        'just an example... not really how i get data...
        Dim value As String = data.Substring(0, 10)

        objProperty.SetValue(Me, value, Nothing)

    Next
End Function
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am always skeptical of calling complicated methods in constructor. what if the method throws exception? with reflection there are high chances of that. then we have an unfinished instance of Person which is in inconsistent state. The method that is called in constructor might have leaked the object reference to some other object (a cache or so), that way the inconsistent object will not even be garbage collected.

Comment: That's an excellent way as well. Having a separate component perform construction of complex objects makes it easier to swap in new ways of object creation.

Comment: Hmmm, swapping in me instead of the private variable still causes an object reference not set error...